# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b spring mail application

Tags: spring, email

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.a(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:114)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1562)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1551)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:935)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:426)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
at com.javapapers.spring.SpringMailSender.sendMail(SpringMailSender.java:50)
at com.javapapers.spring.SpringEmail.main(SpringEmail.java:12)
```

I am trying send email using spring, i am getting this type of Exception

Comment: Can you include more information e.g. the code you are using

Comment: Thanks For Responding FlabbyRabbit,    I am using reguler MailSender Interface and SimpleMailMessage Class api for sending the mail,    The thing is same application works perfectly in another system,  that system and my system having similer properties.  Some sites give suggetions  place jce.jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder   i am doing that thing also still it is not working.